# Load multiple dimensional tables in Qlikview, restricted to data in fact table

Tags: qlikview

I have 3 logical tables: patient, encounter, and location.

My current load script:

```
encounter: 
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, DEPT_ID, ENC_ID, ENC_DATE
FROM    encounter e
WHERE   enc_date >= '10/1/2014' AND enc_date < '10/14/2014'
;

patient:
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, GENDER
FROM    patient p
;

location:
SQL
SELECT  DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, LOC_ID, LOC_NAME
FROM    department d
INNER JOIN location l on d.loc_id=l.loc_id
;
```

I would like to only load patient and department data that is actually associated with the encounter.  As it is written, the script loads all patient and department data.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to interpret your question: downloading the entire tables but restricting what is actually loaded into QlikView, or restricting the amount of data that is requested from your database before loading into QlikView (i.e. rather than downloading the entire tables each time).

In the first case, there are a couple of ways, you can either join the tables together or restrict the loading into each table.

**Joining**

If you do not mind all of your data being in a single table, you can simply add QlikView `JOIN` statements between your SQL statements as follows:

```
encounter: 
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, DEPT_ID, ENC_ID, ENC_DATE
FROM    encounter e
WHERE   enc_date >= '10/1/2014' AND enc_date < '10/14/2014'
;

LEFT JOIN (encounter)

patient:
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, GENDER
FROM    patient p
;

LEFT JOIN (encounter)

location:
SQL
SELECT  DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, LOC_ID, LOC_NAME
FROM    department d
INNER JOIN location l on d.loc_id=l.loc_id
;
```

This will then remove all values in `patient` and `location` which are not relevant.

**Restrict loading into each table**

This method is a little more complex, but keeps the tables separate but reduces the amount of data in them. However, it still queries the entire tables from the data source. You can use the QlikView `exists` function to check the data already loaded for `PAT_ID` and `DEPT_ID` and restrict your other tables accordingly as follows:

```
encounter: 
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, DEPT_ID, ENC_ID, ENC_DATE
FROM    encounter e
WHERE   enc_date >= '10/1/2014' AND enc_date < '10/14/2014'
;

patient_dis:
LOAD DISTINCT
    PAT_ID as PAT_ID_DIS
RESIDENT encounter;

dept_dis:
LOAD DISTINCT
    DEPT_ID as DEPT_ID_DIS
RESIDENT encounter;

patient:
LOAD
    *
WHERE exists(PAT_ID_DIS,PAT_ID);
SQL 
SELECT  PAT_ID, PAT_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, GENDER
FROM    patient p
;

location:
LOAD
    *
WHERE exists(DEPT_ID_DIS, DEPT_ID);
SQL
SELECT  DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, LOC_ID, LOC_NAME
FROM    department d
INNER JOIN location l on d.loc_id=l.loc_id
;

DROP TABLES patient_dis, dept_dis;
```